# Understanding C++ copy and move semantics

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
class Item {
    public:
        
        Item() {
            cout << "constructor" << endl;
        }

        Item(const Item& a) {
            cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
        }

        Item& operator=(const Item& a) {
            cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
        }

        Item(Item && a) {
            cout << "move constructor" << endl;
        }

        Item& operator=(Item && a) {
            cout << "move assignment" << endl;
        }

        ~Item() {
            cout << "destructor" << endl;
        }
};
```

The class `Item` is intended to model let's say a `vector`. The print statements help me understand what will be called.

Now lets say I have:

```
class A {
public:
    Item x;

    A(Item & a) {
        x = std::move(a);
    }
};
```

The idea is that in reality, `Item` will be a `vector` and I want to initialize my class `A` passing it a vector of values. But I don't want any copying of values to happen when I construct `A`. That is what I am trying to verify. I call this code like:

```
Item a;
A q{a};
```

when I run it, I get:

```
constructor
constructor
move assignment
[1]    17802 trace trap  ./main
```

can anyone explain to me why I am getting an exception?

Comment: What does `Item& operator=(Item && a)` return?

Comment: You're getting an exception because of undefined behavior. Your compiler also has room for improvement, it should really warn, at least.

Comment: You probably also want to change your constructor to use initializer list instead of constructing default subobject `x` and then move a value into it. And when moving you usually want a move at the caller too. I thinh that usually `a`would be passed by value to `A` constructor.

Comment: Good viewing: Howard Hinnant's [Everything you ever wanted to know about move semantics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always remember to compile with warnings.

```
example.cpp: In member function ‘Item& Item::operator=(const Item&)’:
example.cpp:19:9: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   18 |             cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
  +++ |+            return *this;
   19 |         }
      |         ^
example.cpp: In member function ‘Item& Item::operator=(Item&&)’:
example.cpp:27:9: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   26 |             cout << "move assignment" << endl;
  +++ |+            return *this;
   27 |         }
      |         ^
```

You declared two functions (namely, your assignment functions) with non-`void` return types and never returned anything. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any case where I would override those functions but not return *this? can I return back the input arg itself to mimic "Java" behavior? In Java a = b, simply copies the reference.

Comment: C++ is not Java, and objects work in fundamentally different ways in C++. Not returning `*this` from an overloaded assignment operator isn't really invalid, but it always eventually ends in tears.

Comment: @morpheus In 99.99% of cases, no. Return `*this` like you're supposed to. For the sake of completeness, there exist DSLs that break this rule. For instance, [Boost.Lambda](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.assignment_and_subscript) makes it so that `_1 = "example"` is a lambda function which assigns to its (presumably lvalue) argument, so the `=` operator on these special lambda objects return something different. But that's very much the exception, not the norm.

Comment: @morpheus - If you absolutely don't want to return anything, you can set the return type to `void`. That stops you from chaining `a = b = c`, but who does that anyway?

Comment: @morpheus • the `return *this;` is idiomatic C++.  An argument can be made for having the return type be `void`, which will be a nice little easter egg for your co-workers to find — but it shouldn't make them too angry.

Comment: @Eljay That has the same energy as `#define true rand()`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, or how it has the same energy.